# How can I left-pad the string representation of a float?

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, padding

I'm trying to convert a single precision floating point number into an ascii representation of the four bytes that make it (sign/exponent/mantissa).
My current code is:

```
Integer.toString(Float.floatToRawIntBits(f),16);
```

`Float.floatToRawIntBits` makes an integer using the same bytes, and then `Integer.toString` creates the ascii digits in hex form (hence the radix = 16 specified).  My problem is that I always need 8 ascii characters plus the optional '-' sign, and `Integer.toString` is not padding with left side zeroes.

Can anybody come up with an elegant solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [String.format()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```
String.format("%08x", Float.floatToRawIntBits(f))
```

This will zero-pad the result and format it as a hexadecimal number. Details on format strings can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#summary).

Comment: Elegant and perfectly functional.  Thanks a lot!!